# How to map multiple values from 1 dataset to another using Python?

Tags: python, data-science

Given `df1`

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

and `df2`

| id3 | id4 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |

I want the results of `df1` to be as follows:

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | c |
| d | b |
| b | a |

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Could you post your attempt at this solution and then detail which error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```py
# lookup mapping from id3 to id4
lookup = df2.set_index('id3').id4
# map df2.id4 to df1 via df2.id3 in a loop
for c in df1:
    df1[c] = df1[c].map(lookup)
df1
```

[image]